# How do I get the $handle for all enqueued scripts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

Is there some way to get the $handle for each script that has been enqueued?

Is there some array that holds all the handles so that I can loop through it and do something using each $handle?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

the `$wp_scripts` global holds all the script data:

```
function wpa54064_inspect_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle;
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa54064_inspect_scripts' );
```

Comment: As of WP 4.2.0 - [`$wp_scripts = wp_scripts();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_scripts/) might be better than accessing the global directly since it will initialize `$wp_scripts` if it has not been set.

Comment: You should add priority `,9999` like `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', wpa54064_inspect_scripts', 9999 );`, else you will be seeing scripts which are dequeued by functions.php file

Answer (score 5):

> Is there some way to get the $handle for each script that has been enqueued?

You could try inspecting `$wp_scripts->queue` at a specific hook but it won't give you a list of all handles used by WordPress, believe it or not.

For example, you could hook into `wp_head`, which runs the `wp_print_scripts` action, to get a list of `$handles` for the stock Twenty Seventeen theme in WP v4.7.5:

```
function get_enqueued_scripts () {
    $scripts = wp_scripts();
    var_dump( array_keys( $scripts->groups ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_enqueued_scripts' );
```

And the list of `$handles` from `$wp_scripts->groups` will output:

[image]

At this point, if you were to compare what exists in `$wp_scripts->queue` you will only see a subset of the above.

Therefore, even `wp_print_scripts` **will not** provide a full list of handles as shown above, if that's what you're after. And it's not possible to always rely on grouped dependencies to get them either.