# Get list of scripts / styles and show file which enqueued them

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, debug, scripts

I want to show what scripts and styles have loaded on a page and which plugin / theme / file has added them to the page.

We can show all scripts and styles using:

```
<?php
  global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;
  var_dump( $wp_scripts );
  var_dump( $wp_styles );
?>
```

Or more elegantly using this answer: [How do I get the $handle for all enqueued scripts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54064/how-do-i-get-the-handle-for-all-enqueued-scripts)

I now want to be able to see where they were enqueued. For example if I had a JS file called foobar.js and it was enqueued by plugins/organge/orange.php I would want to output this file location along with the script.

This is for development to help isolate what is loading what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible the way you think. It *would maybe* be possible if you use [Reflections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) or [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but there's no reliable way to do this. WordPress does not keep a stack or queue where it tracks file names.

The *only* thing I could imagine is just hooking into the action and inside [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_enqueue_scripts/):

```
wp_enqueue_scripts
```

and attach a tracking mechanism of *attached callbacks* there. Note the `s` and that this is not the function that you use to attach scripts to the stack.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (WPSE #152658) Script Loader Callback Inspector */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_filter'][ current_filter() ] );
}, PHP_INT_MAX -1 );
```

This would leave you with a queue of all attached callbacks. You can then trace them back with your IDE.

Comment: kaiser, just to point out, your `debug_backtrace()` link is in German.

Comment: @PieterGoosen That was not by accident. German simply is more accurate. _... fixed_

Comment: LOL OK. Unfortunately I don't understand German, so I'm not aware of that :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this

```
 foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
         $obj = $wp_scripts->registered [$handle];
         $filename = $obj->src;
```

Comment: with ref to the orig question - this would list the js file e.g. foobar.js. The OP wants to list  the php file that enqueued foobar.js - e.g. plugins/organge/orange.php, which your code doesn't list